# perforce add file report wildcards (*, %%x, ...) not allowed in '<path>'

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v

I am using perforce to add files but report：perforce add file report wildcards (*, %%x, ...) not allowed in '<path>'

I've tried using -n -f but still doesn't work：

```
$ p4 add -f -n //space-web/layers/documentation/pages/documentation/...

Wildcards (*, %%x, ...) not allowed in '//space-web/layers/documentation/pages/documentation/[...slug]/index.vue'.
```

How can i add this file, this file is named by file route in nuxt.

Answer (score 0):

`...` is flatly disallowed in Perforce depot filenames; there isn't any escape character for it the way there is for the `*` wildcard.

An ugly workaround might be to tar the file up such that when it's extracted it'll have the right name, and submit the tarfile with a name that's valid in Perforce.